# maximum set size with prime factors less than 20 and greatest common factor restriction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, combinations

[image]

Attached is the question - how should one consider solving it? Would appreciate any clue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are $8$ primes in the set $P=\{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19\}$ of primes below $20$. Since the gcd of any two distinct elements of $S$ is squarefree, for each $p\in S$ there is at most one element of $S$ divisible by $p^2$. The squarefree elements of $S$ can be described by the set of their prime factors, a subset of $P$. Since the gcd of any two elements of $S$ is not $1$, these subsets of $P$ have pairwise non-empty intersections.

**Lemma**: The maximal cardinality of a family of subsets of a set with $n$ elements in which the subsets have pairwise non-empty intersections is $2^{n-1}$.

**Proof**: There are $2^{n-1}$ subsets that contain some fixed element, and they have pairwise non-empty intersections. On the other hand, the family cannot contain both a subset and its complement, so it can contain at most half of the $2^n$ subsets, and thus not more than $2^{n-1}$.

So the maximal number of squarefree numbers with prime factors from $P$ no pair of which is coprime is $2^7=128$. There are at most $8$ additional numbers divisible by $p^2$ for $p\in P$, for a maximal total of $128+8=136$.

Indeed we can exhibit a set that attains this bound, namely the $128$ even squarefree numbers with prime factors in $P$ plus the $8$ numbers $2p^2$ for $p\in P$.